# Git pushing to the past fix

Tags: git, push, commit, history

One of my coworkers was testing a new feature he was adding and had to reset his windows time to 2 days ago.  When he completed his feature he committed and pushed without setting his date back to today...

Now the structure of develop is really messed up with my local one up to date but showing me that I need to pull 2 new commits that are from the past.

We have no idea how to fix this.

I assume we have to somehow reset/rebase the last 2 commits on origin and push them back with the right time.  Because as it looks now, he managed to create an entire new develop branch with just those 2 commits that he pushed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commit timestamps in git are pretty much purely cosmetic -- there's nothing internal that uses them, but some clients might order the display of things using times to help.  So if all that's wrong is the timestamps, I'd encourage you to chalk that down to experience and keep going.

If, on the other hand, you actually do have issues with the structure of your commits on your branches, you've got bigger issues and your question doesn't have enough information to diagnose it.  My recommendation is to create a new clone (probably using --mirror) and to examine it using `gitk --all`.  You might also want to take a look at your reflog to try to work out what your commits *should* look like.  Hopefully then you can work out how to get from what you've got to what you want to have.

Comment: Also, `git log --topo-order` will force the output to topological order (as will `git log --graph`).  The default is "date order", which is usually less confusing, but in this case, more confusing.

Comment: This http://i.imgur.com/oT6w1S3.png is basically what it looks like. And I've noticed in the graph that it created a whole new develop going deep and finishing in 16 august with those 2 commits...and then the 'sane' develop that branches off of some other feature or something..The first one at the bottom is my commit and then the following 2 are his commits..

Comment: It doesn't sound like the timestamps are the problem.  Assuming the work he built on consists of old since-rebased commits you may just need to `rebase --onto` (or `cherry-pick`) his two commits onto the branch where you want them.  The image you linked to doesn't really have any useful information in it, I'm afraid.  Whatever else you do, take backups and do your work on a new clone so you *know* you're not losing any data.

Comment: Okay, what about this? does this help more..? https://i.imgur.com/KrSBMNs.png  The 2 commits at the bottom should be continuing up at the top after i made the merge..the middle line should be the develop line, because I merged it into my feature branch.

Comment: That's more useful :).  I think the issue may be purely cosmetic -- if you routinely merge develop into your feature branches, then that appears to be what's happened here.  It looks different because the timestamps have made your visualisation put the commits in a different order, but the lines between commits are still in the right places.  If you want to, you *can* re-write those commits with a different timestamp, but that *will* cause everyone else to have issues with divergent branches.

Comment: We managed to fix this...in a way...it's working but i think it's a terrible way to fix it. What we've done is we made a new branch from the last commit on develop before it broke and merged into the new origin...it works but now our develop only has those 3 commits and all commits that were in develop are coming from all the other features.. #yolo

Comment: Natively, Git doesn't keep track of which branch commits might be said to have been added to.  Some tools assume that there might be useful information in the order of parents, but other tools break that convention.  So again I think it's just your view that's broken, rather than the actual commit graph.